# Any workaround for reducing size of DocuSign checkboxes and radio buttons?

Tags: asp.net, docusignapi

I've seen several questions from developers hoping to be able to resize the DocuSign template elements (especially checkboxes and radio buttons) so they will better fit over existing forms.  This mostly involves making the template elements smaller as there appears to be a minimum size constraint.

https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W00007HwE8p/can-i-resize-radio-buttons-andor-check-boxes
https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000069k6QX/checkbox-overlap
https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000070dqYM/radio-button-and-checkbox-size

The common answer appears to be:  You cannot make these elements any smaller beyond the minimum supported by DocuSign.  And a common suggestion is to redesign the form to accommodate the DocuSign elements.

So -- if we can't change our forms, what are developers doing as a workaround to address this issue?  Is there any workaround?  Or, is the consensus just to make do the best we can with what's provided?

If you need more information, please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having discussed this with our DocuSign tech rep, there appears to be no true solution to this issue other than redesigning your form to better accommodate the size of DocuSign's checkboxes/radio buttons.

If things should change in the future, please let me know.  Thanks!